# Cannot run installDebug target - "Unable to upload some APKs"

Tags: android, adb

I have created a blank activity project in Android Studio on Ubuntu 14.04. I can do a gradle build and install it to my device in one step using the installDebug target.

I wanted to work with the Nest API though, and I can't get the installDebug target to work. As a start, I downloaded [their sample project](https://developer.nest.com/documentation/cloud/android-nestdk) and tried to build and install it in one go. I get this:

```
:testapp:installDebug FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':testapp:installDebug'.
> com.android.builder.testing.api.DeviceException:com.android.ddmlib.InstallException: Unable to upload some APKs
```

I created an app largely based off of this sample which also isn't working. Does anyone know how to fix this? What's weird is - it *used* to work at some point!!

I tried blowing away my Android SDK and re-installing everything, and also re-cloning the project from Nest's git repo and starting over. It's not working anymore.

Comment: Device or Emulator? Does device has USB debugging enabled?

Comment: @323go Device. Has USB debugging enabled. I see it when running `adb devices`. Works with the other blank app I created

Comment: Got spaces in your apk name?

Comment: @323go the actual name of the APK in the `<name>.apk` ? No...

Comment: @323go I am happy to say I figured out the problem. See my answer.

Comment: That's good, but it's really not a programming issue.

Comment: @323go you're right, but on the surface it looked like a gradle problem, hence my post

Answer (score 2):

I am extremely pleased I have figured out a solution to this problem.

I started to notice something was more seriously up with my adb connection because `adb shell` for example would just hang.

I neglected to mention it, but I was using Ubuntu 14.04 in Oracle Virtualbox as the guest to a Windows 10 host. I think that may have something to do with it.

In VirtualBox, I went to `Devices > USB > USB Settings` and under `Enable USB Controller` I enabled `USB 2.0 (EHCI) Controller`. Previously this was set to 1.1.

My guess is if the application is large enough, USB 1.1 is too slow to transfer all of the data in a timely manner.

I hope this helps someone in the future.

Answer (score 2):

it could be because of three things:

1. If you are using a device, your device is not plugged in correctly. Make sure you can see it when you run adb devices on the commandline.
2. If you are using an emulator,the emulator is not running or it has not booted up yet.
3. Your app is configured to use a buggy version of gradle. Version 1.3.1 is well known to cause this problem.
   The most likely cause of this problem will gradle version 1.3.1.
   In my experience, upgrading gradle did not fix the problem. To fix it, I had to downgrade it to a rather memorable version of 1.2.3.
   Look for com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.3.1 in the android/build.gradle, and update it to com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.2.3.

Answer (score 2):

I had another program that was using the adb and was interfering with the build.

Comment: In my case, the old adb debugging program for my app had not been properly killed and was still running. Finding it in my task manager and killing manually solved the problem.